# How to find out what consumes Linux pty's

Tags: linux, terminal

The number of allocated ptys (/proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr) on my linux server is constantly growing, and exceeds the number of active logins, terminals and screen sessions by orders of magnitude. Only a system restart resets seems to reset it.

How can I find out which process is eating up the pty's?

I tried the suggestion in answer 1, but

```
# lsof -n | grep pts | wc -l
137
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr 
696

# uname -a
Linux spitzer 2.6.32-34-server #77-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 20:54:38 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to grawity's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/282986/which-process-is-eating-ptys-in-my-linux-server) on superuser, what you are seeing is due to a bug in linux. */proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr* is not decremented when a pty is no longer used. That is why lsof is showing a lower number. This was [noticed](http://lkml.org/lkml/2009/11/5/370) in November 2009 but not [fixed](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=24d406a6bf736f7aebdc8fa0f0ec86e0890c6d24) until August 2011.

Answer (score 4):

Ptys are file handles. You can use `lsof` to find out which process is keeping which files open.

```
# lsof -n | grep pts
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work though (main question edited).

Comment: Which kernel/distribution are you running?

Comment: Try `lsof -n | grep 136,`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That includes process ids and memory segments that would happen to match as well.

Answer (score 0):

A pty can have more than one 'file' associated with it.  If you take that into account, the kernel.pty.nr number will match the lsof number.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr

10

lsof -n | fgrep pts | wc -l

58

lsof -n | fgrep pts | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -f9 -d' ' | sort | uniq | wc -l

10
```